# How to change the position of RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making some exercise to get used to Android dev.
So I'm trying to change the position of a Radiogroup in the layout by having the user press buttons

here is the code I'm using, it actually changes the position, but not by much, it barely moves form the original position when I hit center  or right.

```
    else if(group==gravedad)
    {
        if(checkedId==R.id.izq)
        {
            gravedad.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else if(checkedId==R.id.ctr)
        {
            gravedad.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }else if(checkedId==R.id.der)
        {
            gravedad.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }
```

Maybe i messed up the xml...here is how I have set it up

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/gravedad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/izq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Izquierda" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ctr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Centro" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/der"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Derecha" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your api is >11 then you can do like this to change the position of radio group..

```
RadioGroup r=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    r.setX(30);
    r.setY(30);
```

Comment: Okay I found (Kinda) what's causing the problem, I need to work with the layout_gravity rather than just gravity...problem is i look in the  documentation, there's no method asocieated with layout_gravity. So how could I adjust it from the code instead of xml?...